# If $ (A + B)^{-1} = A ^{-1} + B^{-1} $ then $\det A = \det B $.

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n $ $(n \geq  2)$ nonsingular matrices with real entries such that $(A +B)^{-1} = A^{-1} +B^{-1} $ then show that $ \det A = \det B $. Does this also true for complex entries.

my attempt : $(A+B)(A^{-1}+ B^{-1}) = I$ then $I + AB^{-1} +BA^{-1} = 0$ any hint from here how to proceed?

Comment: sorry, i have edited. now it is ok from given assumption.

Comment: Now it is a duplicate. See above ^

Comment: This question is screaming [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity) at me, maybe that will help.